# SAPUI5: Hiding a <List> via setVisibility not working

Tags: listview, visibility, sapui5

I have an xml view with a `sap.m.List` that holds some `sap.m.InputListItems`:

```
<List id="listJobParams">  

  <headerToolbar> ... </headerToolbar>

  <InputListItem label="Partition" id="listItemPartition" visible="false">
    <Select id="partition" selectedKey="{/partition}" />
  </InputListItem>

  ...
</List>
```

Based on certain conditions, I want to either hide the the entire List or only certain InputListItems, using the `setVisibility(true|false)` method.
Hiding/showing input list items based on a condition works fine, but hiding/showing the entire list does not work.

**The problem: once the list has been hidden via `this.byId("listJobParams").setVisibility(false)`, it is not possible to show the list again using `this.byId("listJobParams").setVisibility(true)`;
There is no error in the js console, but also the list does not show up. So I wonder why the InputListItem behave differently than the List.**

Controller code (called from within `onInit()` method):

```
_refreshJobDetailInput : function (channelId, eventId, data) {

  // hiding/showing input list item
  this.byId("listItemPartition").setVisible(data.jobType=='singlePartitionIndexingJob');

  // hiding/showing the entire list DOES NOT WORK; once hidden, it will never appear again, even though the condition is true (and logs as true in the console)
  this.byId("listJobParams").setVisible(data.jobType=='singlePartitionIndexingJob');

}
```

The method is available and documented for `sap.m.list`'s parent class (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#setVisible)

**Update**:

Based on Qualiture's answer below, I tried the following combinations of invalidating and/or rerendering, but it didn't help so far.

```
// 2 parents up is the 'panel'      
this.byId("listJobParams").getParent().getParent().invalidate(); 
this.byId("listJobParams").getParent().getParent().rerender();

// 3 parents up is the 'page'
this.byId("listJobParams").getParent().getParent().getParent().invalidate(); 
this.byId("listJobParams").getParent().getParent().getParent().rerender();

// 4 parents up is the 'xmlview'
this.byId("listJobParams").getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().invalidate(); 
this.byId("listJobParams").getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().rerender();

// this return the shell
this.byId("listJobParams").getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().invalidate();
this.byId("listJobParams").getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().rerender();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `this.byId("listItemPartition").setVisible...` won't work because the object with the `listItemPartition` ID does not exist in DOM. It is just a template for cloning. List items are copied from this template but get own generated ID. Moreover, list items are created dynamically by binding and therefore it has a little sense to manipulate them directly: next invalidate of the list may rebuild the list items with new IDs.
2. Make sure that you do not use an invisible list item as a template for your list.
3. Never use `rerender()` directly. Use `invalidate()`. `invalidate()` calls `rerender()` internally.

Comment: Re 1) listJobParams (InputListItem) works fine with setVisibility(), it's listJobParams (List) that doesn't work with setVisible(), even though this method exists and is documented in the API reference - https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#setVisible

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue (with `sap.ui.commons.Panel` inside an `sap.ui.ux3.Shell`) was posted at SCN (http://scn.sap.com/thread/3546783)

Maybe triggering an invalidate event to your parent container would suffice?

Comment: Thanks for the link, doesn't work for me though. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate workaround is to hook the onAfterRendering event & use jQuery `.css("display", "none")` to hide or show the DOM element. SAPUI5 "`visible : true`" means "in the DOM" and "`visible : false`" means the DOM element is removed or simply not created.